# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame - Not a Repost

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The other version of this question wasn't ever answered, the original poster didn't give a full example of their code...

I have a function that's meant to import a spreadsheet for formatting purposes. Now, the spreadsheet can come in two forms:

1. As a filename string (excel, .csv, etc) to be imported as a DataFrame
2. Directly as a DataFrame (there's another function that may or may not be called to do some preprocessing)

the code looks like

```
def func1(spreadsheet):
    if type(spreadsheet) == pd.DataFrame: 
        df = spreadsheet
    else:
        df_ext = os.path.splitext(spreadsheet)[1]
        etc. etc.
```

If I run this function with a DataFrame, I get the following error:

```
---> 67     if type(spreadsheet) == pd.DataFrame: df = spreadsheet
     68     else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in splitext(p)
    120 
    121 def splitext(p):
--> 122     p = os.fspath(p)
    123     if isinstance(p, bytes):
    124         sep = b'/'

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: So, in this case, why don't you just check if the spreadsheet input is a `string` ( in case it is a filepath ) and then read the dataframe in the else condition

Comment: I tried that. It threw the same error...

Answer (score 2):

So, one way is to just compare with a string and reading the dataframe in the else condition.
The other way would be to use `isinstance`

```py
In [21]: dict1
Out[21]: {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 4, 6, 7], 'c': [2, 3, 4, 5]}

In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

In [28]: isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)
Out[28]: True

In [30]: isinstance(os.getcwd(), pd.DataFrame)
Out[30]: False
```

So, in your case just do this

```
if isinstance(spreadsheet, pd.DataFrame)
```

Comment: I tried switching the if-statement to 'if type(spreadsheet) == str:...' But it threw the exact same error!!

Comment: It throws the error even if I just try 'print(type(spreadsheet))' to see what's going on

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
if type(spreadsheet) == pd.DataFrame:
```

The type of a dataframe is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`. [pandas.DataFrame is a class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) which returns a dataframe when you call it.

Either of these would work:

```
if type(spreadsheet) == type(pd.DataFrame()):


if type(spreadsheet) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame:
```

Comment: If I do 'type(spreadsheet) == pd.DataFrame' outside of the function, it returns *True*. I tried you fix, but it returned the same error